# MD5 Checksum after a file convertion to byte array

Tags: java, file, hash, base64, jax-ws

Here is my problem: I want to take a file and send it in Base64format via a web-service. That web-service also demands me to get MD5 checksum of the file and send it along with the file. That way, it could control whether I send the file properly or not.

I would get off the hash of the file. Until that it is fine. (I check with source code and different MD5 checksom client tools) But then, when I convert it into Base64 and send over there, the other side tells me right away that Hash is wrong. Since I am dealing with a State office I can't get reply swiftly to my calls. I wonder if hash gets corrupted while converting into Base64. Would you please control the code if I am doing it right?

Many thanks in advance;

```
public static Base64Binary MakeBinary(String filePath) {

    Base64Binary b64binary = new Base64Binary();
    b64binary.setContentType("application/x-zip-compressed");

    try {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        try {
            for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); //no doubt here is 0
                //Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off to this byte array output stream.
                System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        b64binary.setValue(bytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return b64binary;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ok I Checked with those people who responsible with the Web Service.. There is nothing wrong with this code. For your information. And many thanks to the readers.